Как происходит соединение ВПН (OpenVPN) + прокси (Proxifier, socks5)?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как происходит соединение OpenVPN и Proxifier? Сначала подключается ВПН OpenVPN, а затем сверху прокси Proxifier? Есть ли возможность каким-то образом посмотреть полный маршрут? Например: домашний ip, vpn, proxy и сайт.
